# Customizing UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, xcode, share, uiactivityviewcontroller, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Recently I was trying to customize `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Specifically removing 3-rd party apps from it.
I have read many articles and topics, but all I found out, is that it’s simply “uncustomizable”. 
I am trying to pass my image to other apps.

So I have a share button, and I need it to show `UIDocumentInteractionController` only with social media services like (**Facebook, Twitter, Message, Mail, etc**) but exclude all other apps that use an image as a basis. I know there is a UTI option, but is there some kind of UTI that will represent only social media options? I didn’t find it. I almost lost my hope :(

But here I opened my Snapseed. And here you go - “Open in” has `UIDocumentInteractionController` with all apps that can work with images. And there is “Share..” button that has only socials. So can someone explain to me what am I missing? How can I achieve close enough results?

[image]

Comment: You can look into https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller.

Comment: I also tried UIActivityViewController but, it only has excludedActivityTypes. So I need to have a really huge list of excluded applications, or I have to access their private function to remove all unwanted types except those in my list, and that’s kind of … wrong, and I don’t think that Apple will approve my app on the verification stage if I do that. Besides all of that, a controller on the screen, I have attached looks like UIDocumentInteractionController, not UIActivityViewController.